# SQL for Email Notification

Tags: sql, vb.net

if “ReqDate” minus  the “period is equal to **System Date** then I want to send email notification to the logged in user. This can be done by using If statement.
But I was asked to do in database so that it can be changed faster.

How can do that?

These condition(“ReqDate” minus  the “period is equal to ) will change very often as per user needs and administrator has to do the change in database with out changing the program.

Comment: In database as opposed to insided a VB.Net application? You alter your application to read the value '5' from a database table. I guess the '5' is part that needs to be changed faster

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *
From ~your table ~
Where DateAdd(day, -XXX, Date) = Convert(datetime, '5/5/2015')
```

~ day --> chang with datetime value you want.

~ XXX : Periode

~ Date : Column with datetime type

So this query will show all data with your criteria to send email notification. Hopefully its you ask for.
Thanks